# Correlation Coefficient over Correlation Determination in linear regression

Tags: statistics, regression, coefficient-of-determination

i am new to machine learning and i am using housing price dataset from kaggle.com to solve regression problem. i want to know the difference between Correlation Coefficient and Correlation Determination and why people use one over the other. for instance, i can see the relation between YearBuild and SalePrice like this

[image]

now, what is the use of Coefficient Determination, why is it used

> if R= Coeffiecient Corellation 
>   then Coefficient Determination = R x R

1. is the percentage view of the Corellation Coeffiecient?
2. is it the relation of an individual feature with the rest of the feature?

Answer (score 1):

The coefficient `R squared` tells you how much of the variance the regression model explains. If it is equal to `0.01` for example, it means that you have explained one percent of the variance. This is useful to know for obvious reasons. Unlike the correlation coefficient, `R squared` is always positive so just tells you that there is (or is not) a linear relationship, but not what its form is.

Comment: so, Correlation Coefficient tells the direction as well the correlation of the variable with another variable where Rsquared tells how much is the variable corellated without telling the direction, is my understanding right?

Comment: i have one more doubt, if you could help me with it. Coefficient Correlation tells the correlation of one variable with another variable and Variance Inflation Vector tells the correlation with one variable with a series of other variable, am i right?

Comment: Variance inflation factor is trying to tell whether the inputs are correlated.